# 10% Rule for Increasing Pace

Tags: running, technique

I've heard of the "10 Percent" rule for increasing distance when running - something like "don't increase your distance for a single run or for the entire week by more than 10 percent per week".  Is there a similar rule of thumb for increasing pace?

Comment: If you voted to close this - why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If pace can be considered intensity of the workout, then [this article](http://sportsmedicine.about.com/od/tipsandtricks/a/10percent.htm) believes that pace should be slowly increased as well:

> Increasing the intensity, time or type of activity too quickly is one
>   common reason for sport injury. To prevent this, many fitness experts
>   recommend that both novice and expert athletes follow the ten percent
>   rule, which sets a limit on increases in weekly training. This
>   guideline simply states that you should increase your activity **no more**
>   than 10 percent per week. That includes distance, intensity, weight
>   lifted and time of exercise.

However, certain types of exercise, such as interval training, relies on judicious use of high intensity activity interspersed with lower intensity activity, so this "10% rule" is more of a guideline since each person's body has a unique tolerance for workout intensity.